# Windows client cannot get cross-domain ticket, but a Linux one (from WSL) can

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, trust-relationship, cross-domain

I am trying to and failing to authenticate my Kerberos credentials when doing ssh **from** a Windows 11 client joined to a Windows Server 2019 domain (let's call it `AD.LOCAL`) **to** a Linux host joined to a domain managed by FreeIPA (let's call it `IPA.LOCAL`).

I already have the trust relationship established as "Forest" trust, and to break down the issues I verified that if I change the client (to Linux), or the destination (to a host on the same domain) it works.

To demonstrate the problem, the command output is trimmed for brevity and the host and IPs anonymized.

❌ From **Windows** to **IPA** host:

```
PS C:\Users\user> ssh -v -K -l user@ad.local host02.ipa.local
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
...
debug1: Authenticating to host02.ipa.local:22 as 'user@ad.local'
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: GSS_S_FAILURE
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
...
```

✅ From **Windows** to **AD** host:

```
PS C:\Users\user> ssh -v -K -l user@ad.local host01.ad.local
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
...
debug1: Authenticating to host01.ad.local:22 as 'user@ad.local'
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: sspi delegation was requested but not fulfilled
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: sspi delegation was requested but not fulfilled
debug1: Authentication succeeded (gssapi-with-mic).
Authenticated to host01.ad.local ([192.168.0.62]:22).
...
```

✅ From **Linux** to **IPA** host:

```
$ ssh -v -K -l user@ad.local host02.ipa.local
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
...
debug1: Authenticating to host02.ipa.local:22 as 'user@ad.local'
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Authentication succeeded (gssapi-with-mic).
Authenticated to host02.ipa.local ([192.168.0.181]:22).
...
```

✅ From **Linux** to **AD** host:

```
$ ssh -v -K -l user@ad.local host01.ad.local
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
...
debug1: Authenticating to host01.ad.local:22 as 'user@ad.local'
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Delegating credentials
debug1: Authentication succeeded (gssapi-with-mic).
Authenticated to host01.ad.local ([192.168.0.62]:22).
...
```

My tickets after running the above commands:

Windows ticket:

```
PS C:\Users\user> klist

Current LogonId is 0:0xe934d3

Cached Tickets: (2)

#0>     Client: user @ AD.LOCAL
        Server: krbtgt/AD.LOCAL @ AD.LOCAL
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
        Ticket Flags 0x40e10000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 6/17/2022 14:55:54 (local)
        End Time:   6/18/2022 0:55:54 (local)
        Renew Time: 6/24/2022 14:55:54 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0x1 -> PRIMARY
        Kdc Called: dc02.ad.local

#1>     Client: user @ AD.LOCAL
        Server: host/host01.ad.local @ AD.LOCAL
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40a10000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 6/17/2022 14:55:54 (local)
        End Time:   6/18/2022 0:55:54 (local)
        Renew Time: 6/24/2022 14:55:54 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0
        Kdc Called: dc02.ad.local
```

Linux ticket:

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:1000
Default principal: user@AD.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/17/2022 14:31:40  06/18/2022 00:30:36  host/host02.ipa.local@
        renew until 06/18/2022 14:30:34
        Ticket server: host/host02.ipa.local@IPA.LOCAL
06/17/2022 14:31:39  06/18/2022 00:30:36  krbtgt/IPA.LOCAL@AD.LOCAL
        renew until 06/18/2022 14:30:34
06/17/2022 14:31:09  06/18/2022 00:30:36  host/host01.ad.local@
        renew until 06/18/2022 14:30:34
        Ticket server: host/host01.ad.local@AD.LOCAL
06/17/2022 14:30:36  06/18/2022 00:30:36  krbtgt/AD.LOCAL@AD.LOCAL
        renew until 06/18/2022 14:30:34
```

And for completeness, I have nothing of interest in `/etc/krb5.conf` on the Linux box, I intentionally commented out pretty much everything.

```
$ grep -v \# /etc/krb5.conf

[libdefaults]
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
```

OS versions

Windows client:

```
PS C:\Users\user> cmd /c ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675]
```

Linux client:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Rocky
Description:    Rocky Linux release 8.6 (Green Obsidian)
Release:        8.6
Codename:       GreenObsidian
```

### Update to answer questions in a comment:

**Windows** client:

```
$ klist get host/host02.ipa.local

Current LogonId is 0:0xe934d3
Error calling API LsaCallAuthenticationPackage (GetTicket substatus): 0x6fb

klist failed with 0xc000018b/-1073741429: The SAM database on the Windows Server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.
```

**Note: The trust is configured as "External" type.**

**Linux** client does not have sssd installed at all.

```
$ rpm -qa sss\* | grep . ; echo $?
1
```

But for completeness:

```
$ env SSSD_KRB5_LOCATOR_DISABLE=1 kvno host/host02.ipa.local
kvno: Configuration file does not specify default realm while parsing principal name host/host02.ipa.local
```

Now, this makes me think that the Linux client tools simply behave differently in respect to resolving hostname credentials. E.g., the following command, when told that the wanted credential is a hostname, it succeeds and it goes gets a `krbtgt` for IPA.LOCAL from AD.LOCAL, then goes to the IPA.LOCAL servers to get the ticket:

```
$ env SSSD_KRB5_LOCATOR_DISABLE=1 kvno -S host host02.ipa.local
host/host02.ipa.local@: kvno = 1
$ klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:1000
Default principal: user@AD.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/20/2022 11:57:32  06/20/2022 21:56:38  host/host02.ipa.local@
        renew until 06/21/2022 11:56:34
        Ticket server: host/host02.ipa.local@IPA.LOCAL
06/20/2022 11:57:32  06/20/2022 21:56:38  krbtgt/IPA.LOCAL@AD.LOCAL
        renew until 06/21/2022 11:56:34
06/20/2022 11:56:38  06/20/2022 21:56:38  krbtgt/AD.LOCAL@AD.LOCAL
        renew until 06/21/2022 11:56:34
```

P.S. Updated the description as we upgraded the trust from "External" type to "Forest" type. Still the same problem.

Comment: What is the AD KDC's response when you do `klist get host/host02.ipa.local` from Windows? Are you using SSSD on Linux? (It comes with krb5 plugins that load realm configuration from sssd directly.) What's the result of `env SSSD_KRB5_LOCATOR_DISABLE=1 kvno host/host02.ipa.local` from Linux?

Comment: Thank you @user1686 and I updated the question with answers to your questions.

Comment: This is probably a DNS problem.

Comment: @paladin I cannot tell if this is a joke (https://isitdns.com/ is the first thing on my mind, too!) but I did do a tcpdump on the Windows client and did not see any DNS queries of interest. Note that if I use a Linux client which is WSL on the same Windows host (so it uses the same host for DNS), I get to do what I am trying to.

Comment: No, this is no joke. I suggest you double check all important domains with `nslookup` on Windows and WSL.